# django tag { % block content % } isn't working

Tags: html, django, django-templates, pycharm, tags

so i just started learning django, i understand the basic tag blocks but it didn't works well on my page. i have page called index.html and question.html

i write like this in index.html

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            sum content
        </div>
        <div>
            { % block content % }

            { % endblock % }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and like this in question.html :

```
{ % extends 'index.html' % }

{ % block content % }
<<my content>>
{ % endblock % }
```

but the content in question.html didn't show up in index.html. i've checked my setting and didn't have django-stub like in other case.

and if you want to know the structure, it goes like :

```
djangoProject1
   >djangoProject1
   >myweb
   >static
   >templates
      -index.html
      -question.html
```

this is my views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def question(request):
    return render(request, 'question.html')


def formdata(request):
    nama = request.POST.get("namaa")
    umur = request.POST.get("umur")
    komorbid = request.POST.get("penyakit_bawaan")
    ruang = request.POST.get("ketersediaan_ruang")
    demam = request.POST.get("demam")
    lelah = request.POST.get("lelah")
    batuk = request.POST.get("batuk")
    nyeri = request.POST.get("nyeri")
    tersumbat = request.POST.get("tersumbat")
    pilek = request.POST.get("pilek")
    sakit_kepala = request.POST.get("sakit_kepala")
    tenggorokan = request.POST.get("tenggorokan")
    diare = request.POST.get("diare")
    hilang_cium = request.POST.get("hilang_penciuman")
    ruam = request.POST.get("ruam")
    sesak = request.POST.get("sesak")
    sulit_gerak = request.POST.get("sulit_gerak")
    nyeri_dada = request.POST.get("nyeri_dada")
    hasil_rekomendasi = request.POST("hasil_rekomendasi")

    data_resp = DataResponden(nama=nama, umur=umur, penyakit_bawaan=komorbid, ketersediaan_ruang=ruang, demam=demam,
                              lelah=lelah, batuk=batuk, nyeri=nyeri, tersumbat=tersumbat, pilek=pilek,
                              sakit_kepala=sakit_kepala, tenggorokan=tenggorokan, diare=diare,
                              hilang_penciuman=hilang_cium, ruam=ruam, sesak=sesak, sulit_gerak=sulit_gerak,
                              nyeri_dada=nyeri_dada, hasil_rekomendasi=hasil_rekomendasi)
    data_resp.save()
    return render(request, 'question.html')
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By "didn't show up" do you mean when you check the page source when visiting the website? Because the template files remain like this, django handles everything during runtime and renders a combined page.

Comment: Why are there spaces between the tags `{ % extends 'index.html' % }` it should be `{% extends 'index.html' %}` remove those spaces everywhere and it should work.

Comment: @shriakhilc yes, i checked /question it showed up, but if i checked /index, the content in question didn't show up..

Comment: @Celoo can you post the code in your `views.py`? if `/index` is loading just index.html, then it will not have the content from question, the div will be empty. That is the base file. `/question` will have items because you are extending the base html and then overriding the content tag to insert content.

Comment: @shriakhilc updated the views.py, "/question will have items because you are extending the base html and then overriding the content tag to insert content." <br/> so this means my /question will have /index's content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have some confusion regarding how templates work. `index.html` is a parent/base template, because it is being extended (through the `{% extends 'index.html' %}` tag). `question.html` is a child template, which means if you make no changes, it will inherit everything from `index.html`.

A child template can override parts of the parent template by using `{% block %}` tags. So when the webpage is getting rendered, the code from the block in the parent is not used at all (if there was any). When you directly render the parent template, there will be no such replacement since it does not extend anything.

So the rendered HTML for your files should be as follows

`index.html`

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            sum content
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

`question.html`

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            sum content
        </div>
        <div>
            <<my content>>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So yeah, content in `question.html` is not supposed to show up in `index.html`. It works the other way around, with the entire structure of `index.html` being used for `question.html`, except for the things you override.

If you want index to have some content by default, you can have code inside the `content` block. It will be replaced by any child templates if necessary, but when you load just `index.html` it will still be visible.

---

If you are actually trying to insert something into `index.html`, take a look at the [`include` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include). This allows for re-using common sections of the website across webpages. But you would **not** extend the base template inside any template you are planning to include.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the spaces in tag blocks everywhere like this:

Change this:

```
{ % block content % }
```

To this:

```
{% block content %}
```

Similarly with other tag blocks.

Comment: @shriakhilc is it working now ?

Comment: isn't working.. thanks tho

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: there's no error found but there's a small sign/mark on the left {% block content %}. it says : is overriden in inheritors

Comment: What is inhenritos ?

Comment: it's inheritors, my bad

Comment: Have you removed spaces for every block tag ? Including extends e.t.c ?

Comment: yes i have, but i can't remove space between extends and 'index.html', it become a problem

Comment: extends should be this `{% extends 'index.html' %}`

Comment: tried that too but still isn't working